# put text in Graph

Tags: android, canvas

currently use the DrawText of and drawRect put in same (x,y) like overlap to implement

now i want to ask is able to insert text directly in the graphics ?

or how to let text fit to rect?

ex: canvas.drawRect(20, 205, 200, 280, paint);
    then i want to put text in this rect

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question, I'm struggling to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: ex: canvas.drawRect(20, 205, 200, 280, paint); then i want to put text in this rect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "put" text into a rect, you simply draw the text after the rect.
If coordinates of rect are (0,0) then the coordinates of the text could be (2,2).
If your text is to long to fit into the rect, you'll have to setTextSize on the paint object.

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes,but i wonder to know is there have other way to achieve this work   @@"

Comment: I believe this is the only way to achieve this.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCbqJuzqSMo   how to achieve this app's effect

Answer (score 1):

use canvas for inserting text draw rectangle or whatever images using alignment property u can fit it into center